# SQL Decode format numbers only

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I want to format amounts to salary format, e.g. 10000 becomes 10,000, so I use `to_char(amount, '99,999,99')`

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'Basic Salary',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0)) Salary,
SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'Transportation Allowance',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0)) Transportation,
SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'GOSI Processing',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0)) GOSI, 
SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'Housing Allowance',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0)) Housing

FROM values v,
values_types vt,
elements e


WHERE vt.value_type = 'Amount'
```

this gives error `invalid number` because not all values are numbers until `value_type` is equal to `Amount` but I guess `decode` check all values anyway although what I know is that the execution begins with `from` then `where` then `select`, what's going wrong here?

Comment: Logically the execution proceeds from `from` to `where` to `select`, however that's not guaranteed physically. The query optimiser might do things in different orders. You'd have to look at the query plan to be sure, and anyway that might change depending on the amount of data.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax (`JOIN` clause) instead of the comma-separated list of tables.

Comment: "...but I guess decode check all values anyway..." -- No. The expressions in the select list are only evaluated for the selected rows.

Comment: Have you left the implicit join conditions out of your `where` clause to simplify the query for posting, or are you really doing a cartesian product of those three tables? (Using explicit join syntax would prevent you doing that by accident...) That would explain why you're getting the error even if all the `Amount`-related values can be converted to numbers, as you're picking up *all* values if you aren't joining properly. Otherwise, on recent versions you can use an explicit `to_number()` with the `on conversion error` clause; or `validate_conversion()` to look for unexpected values.

Comment: of course I'm using ```join``` but i omitted the rest of the code to make it short

Comment: the code was working fine before i use ```decode```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you added `decode(...)`, but it looks like you might have actually added `sum(decode(...))`.

You are converting your values to strings with `to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99')`, so your `decode()` generates a string - the default `0` will be converted to `'0'` - giving you a value like `'1,234,56'`. Then you are aggregating those, so `sum()` has to implicitly convert those strings to numbers - and it is throwing the error when it tries to do that:

```
select to_number('1,234,56') from dual
```

will also get "ORA-01722: invalid number", unless you supply a similar format mask so it knows how to interpret it. You *could* do that, e.g.:

```
SUM(to_number(DECODE(e.element_name,'Basic Salary',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0),'99,999,99'))
```

... but it's maybe more obvious that something is strange, and even if you did, you would end up with a number, not a formatted string.

So instead of doing:

```
SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'Basic Salary',to_char(v.screen_entry_value,'99,999,99'),0))
```

you should format the result *after* aggregating:

```
to_char(SUM(DECODE(e.element_name,'Basic Salary',v.screen_entry_value,0)),'99,999,99')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bVQ99zQ1) with dummy tables, data and joins.